# Reactivating Xampp and Web Files

Tags: xampp

So something happened to my operating system that required me to format my PC. 
I was able to save my xampp folder and its web files in it.

My question is, is it possible to reactivate Xampp and its web files the way it was like nothing happened? How?
Or I really have to start a new Xampp installation and do everything one by one.

Please help. I will really appreciate it. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

To be safe, just start a new Xampp installation. Important registry entries are lost when you reformat your PC.